# safari loads css/js very slow on client certificate SSL website

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, mobile, safari

I have a website where I use client certificates for accessing the site and it runs with SSL required. It runs on IIS 8.5 on a windows server 2012 R2.

All my css and javascript is minified into 4 seperate files

> app.js -> Our own javascript
>
> app.css -> Our own css
>
> vendor.js -> External javascript libraries
>
> vendor.css -> External css libraries

All of these files are minified and placed locally on the server.

The site works very well when using chrome or IE from a computer, but when using safari (only tried safari 5 on PC and latest safari on iphone 6/7) the page can stuck in a "loading" mode. The does not happend every time, and when it does it often helps with clearing the cache in safari and try again.

The website also uses local storage to save some userdata, and a cookie that stores a token for authentication. Not sure if this is useful information, just throwing it out there.

It can connect to the webserver, since we can see the EV+ certificate.

When debugging the phone on a mac, or safari on a PC and looking at the network tab in the developer window I can see that sometimes it takes really long time for the browser to load some of the css and/or javascript files.

Sometimes it appears to be vendor.js, and sometimes app.css, and sometimes the other ones. There seems to be no logic to me, that its always the same files etc.

The site is .NET 4.6 site, running with angularjs, signalr 2.2.1 and html5 in the front.

We have tried

- Monotoring IIS Logs and network traffic
- Remove sourcemap on css/js to reduce file size
- Tried reference `signalr/hubs` (the generated js file). And also tried copying the content into vendor.js so there is a local version instead

Without any success ATM. I would really appreciate help, feeling stuck on this one.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<del>It may be dynamic compression. Are you using Brotli compression on the server?</del>

I suggest a detailed analysis of HTTP Request and Response headers. There may be a discrepancy resulting in this unexpected behaviour. I would follow this up with scouring the Safari bug tracker.

The SSL certificate itself may be the issue, or rather Safari's interpretation of policies.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No I'm not. Will check it out

Comment: But the file sizes quite small. For example vendor.js is the biggest and is 1.7mb, while sometimes safari stucks on app.js that is 32kb (according to chrome network tab)

Comment: I suggested Dynamic compression because Brotli is a relatively new compresson format, and I've had some issues with IIS (webserver) when it comes to the server trying to compress the files on first request (hence 'dynamic' compression)

Comment: I'm sure you've already done it but I can only suggest a full web server trace, detailed analysis of both HTTP traffic (with HTTP proxy such as Fiddler, Charles etc) and specifically the HTTP request and response headers.

Comment: If it isn't Safari reacting to something slightly off, then it must be something inside the workstation environment. DNS, proxies, caching, firewall, or the result of a rare browser bug error triggered by a specific piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Will continue to investigate and will for sure come back with any answer, if I find it :)

Comment: Since brotli does not support safari I believe it wont do any difference Im afraid http://caniuse.com/#search=brotli